# IBM MQ : command to check remote queue managers on remote servers

Tags: linux, ibm-mq

Is there any command similar to `dspmq` to check a queue managers status on a remote server.

Also i am using the command below to check if a queue exists on queue manager or not. But this command only executes if queue is present on the same server.

```
echo 'DISPLAY QLOCAL(*)' | runmqsc -e [queue manager] |grep [queuename]
```

I am stuck as I have a server for which queue is hosted on a different server.

When I execute the above commands they fail.

Are there any commands to check a queue and queue manager on a remote server.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want to check about the queue on a remote queue manager (Qmgr)?  Do you just want to check the existence of the queue?  What about the remote Qmgr are you trying to check, are you trying to see if it is running?  Do you manage that remote Qmgr, if not what type of access do you have to the remote Qmgr? (for instance are you connecting as a MQ client to the remote Qmgr or do you have a Sender channel to the remote Qmgr?)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you can make a client connection to the remote queue manager (e.g. with MQSERVER or MQCHLLIB/MQCHLTAB), you could use the client mode connection (-c) option on that runmqsc command from v8 onwards. Read more about this in the link below.

[MQ V8 - Client MQSC](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/bitesize_blogging_mq_v8_client_mqsc)

So then, for example, your commands would be:-

```
export MQSERVER='channel-name/TCP/hostname(port)'
echo 'DISPLAY QLOCAL(queuename)' | runmqsc -c queue-manager
```

You'll have to replace `channel-name`, `hostname`, and `port` with your own values of course.

Note I have changed the example from that which you cited, to put the queue name in the `DISPLAY QLOCAL` command, save you grepping afterwards, you can just ask the queue manager for only the queue you are interested in.

Alternatively if your local and remote queue managers are connected, and you have appropriate security and definitions, you can route the MQSC command through your local queue manager to your remote queue manager with the -w option. Read more here.

[Issuing MQSC commands on a remote queue manager](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.adm.doc/q021190_.htm)